# Is there any way to express one exact concave form using max, min, etc functions?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis, cvx

Consider the following piecewise monotonically increasing, concave, and smooth function defined over $x\in[0,\infty)$:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle 2\ln\left(\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{5}{3}\right), & \text{if } x\le8,\\
\ln(1+x), & \text{if } x>8.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable over any point $[0, \infty)$.

The following figure represents the above function $f(x)$:
[image]

---

In this regard, can it be possible to express the above function in one exact concave function?
I guess that it can be done using $\max$ and $\min$ functions:

- $\max$ function is convex,
- $\min$ function is concave.

Actually, I am using the software, called CVX.
In addition, my real goal is to find $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ that maximizes $\sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x_i)$ subject to $x_i\ge0, \forall i$, and $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \le L$, where $L$ is given positive value. For each $i$, $f_i(x)$ is piecewise monotonically increasing, concave, smooth function, like the above $f(x)$.

Comment: This is an "exact" (do you mean closed form?) concave function, what you are asking doesn't make sense. You don't like that it's defined piecewise?

Comment: @TSF Yes, I want to convert it into one closed-form function. Since, the convex programming tool I am using does not accept piecewise form. More exactly, it does not accept the situation where $x$ is posed in the condition (e.g., $x\le8$) although $x$ is a design variable. Hence, some people redefine a function to implement it. For example, when $f$ is defined as $f(x)=-x$ for negative $x$, $f(x)=x$ for nonnegative $x$, some experts redefine it as $f(x) = \max(-x,0) + \max(x,0)$, which is a convex form.

Comment: The problem is (for me ) that on both intervals takes greater values the same (blue courbe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's translate everything to be at the origin. Let $f(x)=2\ln(x/6 + 5/3)$ and $g(x) = \log(x+1)$. Define the following functions,

$$\tilde{f}(x) = f(x+8)$$

and

$$\tilde{g}(x) = g(x+8).$$

Notice that $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{g}(0)$ since $f(8)=g(8)$.

Furthermore define

$$\hat{f}(x) = \tilde{f}(x)-\tilde{f}(0)$$

and

$$\hat{g}(x) = \tilde{g}(x) - \tilde{f}(0).$$

Then we can almost write the function we want as,

$$\hat{h}(x) = \max(\hat{g}(x),0) + \min(\hat{f}(x),0),$$

except that this has been translated so we must translate back,

$$h(x) = \hat{h}(x-8) + \tilde{f}(0).$$

So our final function is simply $h(x)$.

I leave it to you to understand why it's still concave and to compute explicitly all the functions.

Edit: made notation more consistent by switching $\hat{h}(x)$ and $h(x)$.